# Twice-differentiable function such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=0$ for every positive integer $n$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Q. Let $f :\mathbb R → \mathbb R$ be a twice-differentiable function such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=0$ for every positive  integer $n$. Then

1. $f(0)=0$
2. $f'(0)=0$
3. $f''(0)=0$
4. $f$ is a non zero polynomial

We can say 4 is not correct by taking   $f(x)=x^4 \sin \frac{1}{x}$.

How to prove the rest of them?

Comment: Well, an easier counterexample to $4$ is $f(x)= 0$.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that no non-zero polynomial can have infinitely many zeroes.

Comment: $f(x)=x^4\sin\frac1x$ is not an admissible example for more reasons than one. Its domain is not $\Bbb R$ and $f(\frac1n)\ne0$. Perhaps you meant $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^4\sin\frac{\pi}x,&x\ne0\\0,&x=0\end{cases}$?

Comment: Have you solved the question? Can anyone post the Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a function in $\mathcal C^2(\mathbf R)$, including at $0$, you can take the function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^5\sin\frac\pi x&\text{ if }x\ne 0,\\ 0&\text{ if }x=0.
\end{cases}$$
(With a smaller integer exponent for $x$, it is not twice continuously differentiable at $0$.)

Comment: What about the derivatives of f at x=0

Comment: They're equal to $0$, as you can easily check.

Comment: The question says twice-differentiable, not twice continuously-differentiable. Still, how does this answer the question? I don't think the question is about which option may be true, but which option is definitely true.

Comment: It simply confirms the O.P.'s answer, with a nicer function. The question is not very explicit, I would add.

Comment: How to prove f"(0)=0

Comment: You first first compute $f'(x) $ for $x\ne 0$ and show $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)=0$, so by Darboux's theorem, $f'(0)$ exists and is equal to $0$. For $f''(0)$, do the same: compute $f''(x)$ for $x\ne 0$ and show its limit as $x$ tends to $0$ is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 3):

$\forall n\in\Bbb N \,\exists x_n\in (1/(n+1),\,1/n): (\,f'(x_n)=\frac {f(1/n)-f(1/(n+1))}{1/n-1/(n+1)}=0\,).$

Now $f'$ is continuous because $f''$ exists, so $f'(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f'(x_n)=0.$

Now  $f'(0)=0$, so $f''(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {f'(x_n)-f'(0)}{x_n-0}=0.$

And $f$ is continuous because $f'$ exists, so $f(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty \,:n\in \Bbb N}f(1/n)=0.$

Comment: We could instead do the last line $f(0)=0$ first, and then $f'(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {f(1/n)-f(0)}{1/n-0}=0.$